# Is there a way to protect against mdk3 attacks?

Tags: network, wifi, attack-prevention, deauth-attack

I've got a home network using Wi-Fi.
Someone is using mdk3 and disconnects users from the Access Point, whether they are Android or Windows Phone or Windows 10 desktop or Apple computers.

Is there a way to protect against attacks?
Is there a way to know the attacker?

Comment: Such attacks require the attacker to be nearby. Look around.

Comment: i know that attacker require to be  nearby

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to protect against attacks?

Sadly you cannot stop an attacker from sending deauthentication packets.

But to minimize damage make sure you use WPA2 with a long good password. An attacker will usually send deauthentication packets so he can capture a handshake and brute force it to gain the WiFi password. By having a hard to crack password you are making the attack much harder and longer and in some cases almost impossible.

> Is there a way to know attacker ?

As said in the comments, the attacker is probably close by so walk around a little and find him.

You can read a little more about the subject in [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20219/preventing-deauthentication-attacks) answer.

Comment: i saw in other sites you can connect using by  bssid but using linux ... is this way to solve disconnected in my phone .. and i can't find any program  to do this connect in android store

Comment: I do now know of a program but I would assume that even if there was one it would require you to root your phone

Comment: I already root my phone what is program or send link please

Answer (score -3):

Hide your wifi SSID, change your channel and lower your router signal strength.

If still facing a problem, then install Wireshark. Then you will know who is attacking.

Comment: None of those things will prevent someone who knows your network exists. Wireshark will not tell you who is attacking. None of this answer will help.