# How to prevent WiFi jammer attack?

Tags: wireless

How can I prevent a WiFi jammer attack on my wireless network?

For example if I send a deauth (deauthentication) packet with aircrack-ng on Kali Linux for a specific client, he/she can't use WiFi.
and if there is differences between jamming and deauthentication attack, whats that?

Comment: A deauthentication attack is not a jamming attack.

Comment: what is difference between jamming and deauthentication attack?

Comment: I think that jamming refers to producing excessive noise on the particular Radio Frequency range that WiFi relies upon. On the other hand, deauth is a way of abusing the WiFi protocol. The former requires a strong enough radio transmitter, and the latter can use a standard WiFi antenna assuming you are using the appropriate computer program.

Comment: Exactly. Jamming is just screaming 2.4GHz noise, valid deauth packets are something you have build carefully.

Answer (score 0):

There's not really a solution to it. Deauth packets are part of the protocol. If you're using WPA, someone can send deauth packets. One method of mitigation would preparing for wireless location. If you notice an attack, you can quickly triangulate and neutralize the source.

[This question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20219/preventing-deauthentication-attacks) also deals more specifically with making sure you aren't vulnerable to other issues that can come from a deauth.